# How to check if parameter/variable is available for Jenkins "Build with Parameters" in Groovy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We used to be able to check if a parameter is available via:

```
binding.variables.containsKey()
```

or

```
getBinding().hasVariable()
```

But that no longer works at least as of Jenkins v 2.39.  (These functions work for variables set within the groovy script but not the parameters from 'Build with Parameters'.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `binding.variables.containsKey()` to check, you should use:

```
params.containsKey()
```